# Kotlin DTO Entity mapping recursion problem

Tags: spring, kotlin

So I'm tring to map a Dto to Entity and vice versa but since I have a bidirectional connection between them I run into a recursion error is there an easy fix for this I just started using kotlin and have not found any solutions yet.

These are my extension classes.

**RegistrationRuleExtension.kt**

```
fun RegistrationRuleEntity.toDto() = RegistrationRuleDto(
    id = id,
    count = count,
    description = description,
    tier = tier,
    licenses = licenses?.map { license -> license.toDto()}
)

fun RegistrationRuleDto.toEntity() = RegistrationRuleEntity(
        id = id,
        count = count,
        description = description,
        tier = tier,
        licenses = licenses?.map { license -> license.toEntity()}
)
```

**LicenseExtension.kt**

```
fun LicenseEntity.toDto() = LicenseDto(
        id = id,
        name = name,
        licenseId = licenseId,
        rules = rules?.map { rule -> rule.toDto() },
        version = version
)

fun LicenseDto.toEntity() = LicenseEntity(
        id = id,
        name = name,
        licenseId = licenseId,
        rules = rules?.map { rule -> rule.toEntity() },
        version = version
)
```

If I understand it right the problem is that my license call the for the .toDto on my rule and then the rule wants to call the .toDto on my license and it gets into an infinite loop.

Thanks for the answers in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So there were a few ideas I got from friends and coworkers.

My first idea:

Since the licence knows which rules it has there is not really a reason for me to get the licenses on the rules therefor I can just set it null in my case.

The second idea:

I only store the ids of the rules on the licence and if I need the rule I request them by their ids.

If you have any other ides feel free to comment it ect. :D